# pgfplots: axis equal at different scales

Tags: pgfplots

I have:

[image]

What do I have to set, that x-units (0,1,2,...,24) have the same width as the height of the y-units (100,...,800).

So that the grid's  rectangles becomes squares like here

[image]

Is there something with

```
%axis equal, 
%unit vector ratio=1 1,
%x=0.1cm*3, y=0.001cm*3,
```

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass[border=5pt, tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{per-mode=fraction,
%fraction-function=\tfrac
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\footnotesize,
]
\begin{axis}[
xlabel={$t\, [\si{\hour}]$},
ylabel={$\displaystyle f(t)\, \left[   \si{\metre\cubed\per\hour} \right]$},
title={$f(t)=\frac14 t^3 -12t^2 +144t +250$},
axis lines=middle, % so kein Ursprung
axis x line=bottom,  % so ein Ursprung
%axis equal, 
%unit vector ratio=1 1,
%x=0.1cm*3, y=0.001cm*3,
xmin=0, xmax=25.5,
ymin=0, ymax=800,
xtick={0,2,...,24},
ytick={100,200,...,800},
xlabel style={anchor= south east},
ylabel style={anchor= north west},
grid=major, 
%enlarge x limits={abs=1.1, upper},
enlarge y limits={rel=0.1, upper},
]
\addplot[thick, smooth, samples=222, domain=0:25, variable=\t] {0.25*t^3-12*t^2+144*t+250};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you want is that the division on the x-axis (that are 13) have the same size as the ones of the y-axis (8), you can do the following:

1. remove automatic scaling of the axis, like `enlarge y limits`
2. use `scale only axis`, which will apply `width` and `length` just to the axis
3. choose a vertical and a horizontal width proportional to the number of divisions.

```latex
\documentclass[border=5pt, tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{per-mode=fraction,
%fraction-function=\tfrac
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\footnotesize,
]
\begin{axis}[
xlabel={$t\, [\si{\hour}]$},
ylabel={$\displaystyle f(t)\, \left[   \si{\metre\cubed\per\hour} \right]$},
title={$f(t)=\frac14 t^3 -12t^2 +144t +250$},
axis lines=middle, % so kein Ursprung
axis x line=bottom,  % so ein Ursprung
scale only axis, 
% 6.15cm = 10cm * hor_division * vert_divisions =10cm/13*8 
width=10cm, height=6.15cm,
xmin=0, xmax=26,
ymin=0, ymax=800,
xtick={0,2,...,26},
ytick={100,200,...,800},
xlabel style={anchor= south east},
ylabel style={anchor= north west},
grid=major, 
]
\addplot[thick, smooth, samples=222, domain=0:25, variable=\t] {0.25*t^3-12*t^2+144*t+250};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I solved it this way:

`\pgfmathsetlengthmacro\u{6.5mm}`

and then

`x=0.5*\u, y=0.01*\u`

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5pt, tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{per-mode=fraction,
%fraction-function=\tfrac
}

\pgfmathsetlengthmacro\u{6.5mm}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\footnotesize,
]
\begin{axis}[
xlabel={$t\, [\si{\hour}]$},
ylabel={$\displaystyle f(t)\, \left[   \si{\metre\cubed\per\hour} \right]$},
title={$f(t)=\frac14 t^3 -12t^2 +144t +250$},
axis lines=middle, % so kein Ursprung
axis x line=bottom,  % so ein Ursprung
x=0.5*\u, y=0.01*\u,
xmin=0, xmax=25.5,
ymin=0, ymax=800,
xtick={0,2,...,24},
ytick={100,200,...,800},
xlabel style={anchor= south east},
ylabel style={anchor= north west},
grid=major, 
%enlarge x limits={abs=1.1, upper},
enlarge y limits={rel=0.1, upper},
]
\addplot[thick, smooth, samples=222, domain=0:25, variable=\t] {0.25*t^3-12*t^2+144*t+250};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```